# What would be the American equivalent of "Dickensian"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, american-english

An event, be it historical or cultural, is often expressed by the time period in which it occurred, or is reminiscent of.

For instance, British speakers will use the term *Dickensian* for people, events or situations that remind them of the novels of Charles Dickens set in the [Victorian era](http://www.victorianweb.org/authors/dickens/diniejko.html).

> The photograph from the past is the proud possession of Mrs Vivienne Smith of Mitchell Street, Colne, whose husband, James, is the most enterprising character, being, in both business and pleasure, a true **Dickensian personality**  ([source](http://www.pendletoday.co.uk/lifestyle/day-corrie-writer-peter-celebated-his-first-communion-1-1705207))

and

> In a world where microwaves, televisions and even fast wi-fi connections are deemed basic household necessities, it is hard to believe these images of Glasgow slums are less than 50 years old.
>   Families living in one room without running water and electricity but surrounded by damp and vermin might sound **Dickensian**. Yet it was reality for many living in the city’s squalid tenements in the late 1960s and early 1970s.
>   *[Mail Online](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3271583/A-bleak-portrait-Dickensian-poverty-Glasgow-s-slums-1970s-Photos-families-living-one-room-without-running-water-electricity-rats-rubble-50-years-ago.html)*

From UK [Reuters](http://uk.reuters.com/article/us-britain-children-idUKTRE5894E620090910), written in 2009, we have the following

> **UK children still living in "Dickensian" poverty**
>   Some British children are living in such poverty that their lives mirror the suffering of those in the "times of Dickens," a teachers' union leader says

Supposing, for instance, I wanted to write about abject poverty today in the US and compare it to the Great Depression period, which American author would evoke the same imagery and connotations as Dickens? In other words, which appropriate American author's name could I use as an adjective?

Comment: Dickens is significant not just for having been writing at a time when poverty was severe and rife, but for highlighting it and bringing information about the squalor, overcrowding and exploitation of the working class to the attention of the middle and upper classes. http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-16907648 So it might be useful to look for people who played a similar role in America.

Comment: I think that "*The Great Depression*" is the American "*author*" that is often cited to refer that period or to make analogies in terms of unemployment, poverty, depression etc.

Comment: @Josh Yes, but I was wondering if a particular  American author was associated with that particular era. It doesn't have to be the Great Depression, it could be at the turn of the 20th century in NYC for example. And Great Depression is difficult to use as an adjective, if not impossible.

Comment: What's wrong with "Dickensian"?

Comment: @HotLicks There's nothing wrong with Dickensian but if I wanted to write about Black poverty in Chicago for instance, it would sound inappropriate, and non-American.

Comment: @mari-louA while I can see why you'd want to go for an American author, in the US we all grow up reading Dickens in school (Great Expectations or Tale of Two Cities being the most common, ime). Even if someone hasn't read Dickens, they probably will recognize the meaning from having heard dickensian in context, much as we do with terms like kafkaesque, quixotic, or orwellian.

Comment: @guifa well I didn't know that American schoolchildren read Charles Dickens, I've always heard it was Mark Twain, Fitzgerald, and Walt Whitman. If you can find an American source that uses Dickensian, metaphorically, please post it in an answer. And everyone studies Shakespeare at one point or the other :)

Comment: For alternatives, Upton Sinclair's 'The Jungle' is famous for depicting the squalor of the poor immigrants around Chicago's turn of the century slaughter-house, Richard Wright's 'Native Son' about the squalor of living in poor black areas in Chicago in the 30's, Algren's 'Man with the Golden Arm' blah blha poor blah blah Chicago blah blah 50's. As famous as these novels are, including Steinbeck's, none of them have appropriate eponymous adjectives. Just qualify: eg '_almost_ Dickensian', 'the nearest thing the US has to Dickensian',

Comment: The use of the term "Dickensian" is in no way restricted to describing poor social conditions. It is often used in relation to character and personality. The popularity of Dickens in the US (you will remember he toured giving readings of his works) was because of the characters and the plots in his books, not because of his description of social conditions, which would have been similar for the immigrants in New York clammering to hear what had happened to Little Nell.

Comment: @David yes, I do agree, and I did give an example of Dickensian used with *personality*, I had tried looking for examples with *a Dickensian character* but they nearly all referred to actual figures from his novels. But do Americans use Dickensian in connection with the US? I don't think so ...

Comment: @Mari-LouA — I suspect that you are right, but not having lived in the US for over 40 years I am not the person to ask. It may be something to do with differences in popular culture and literary tradition. Most Brits of my generation had to read Dickens at school. I managed to avoid this  and hence was able to enjoy the novels later in life when I was better able to appreciate them (and to forgive the mawlishness with which he generally treated relations between the sexes).

Comment: The problem you'll have is that few American authors are so closely associated with slum-like poverty as Dickens.  Many have written about it, not not so exclusively.

Comment: Words such as *Dickensian* and *Victorian* are as AmE as they are BrE. They are no doubt AusE etc., as well. They are simply English. Current BrE is no more 19th-century English (or 18th or...) than is current AmE. Oh, and American school children (to the extent that they read!) do not read only American authors. ;-)

Comment: @Drew I don't doubt Americans are familiar with Charles Dickens, nor would they be stumped faced with the adjective Dickensian, but would a typical American speaker ever associate the adjective with the homeless, and the down-and-outs living in the US? I believe that Dickens is quintessentially English (not even British)  whereas Shakespeare is universal. If you mention the  ***Victorian era*** that conjures up the images of destitution, wealth, the social classes, the empire etc... What adjective could I use in place of Dickensian that would evoke similar reactions from an American reader?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Yes, I think an American who understands *Dickensian* would so associate it. Whether a "typical" American understands (or has even heard of) *Dickensian* is another question - dunno. The *Victorian era* applies nearly worldwide (the world was, after all, the Empire's oyster). I don't think there is a single adjective that evokes all of those things in the same way for an American frame, but pretty much the same term applies to the US for the same period (not quite, but pretty much, for the industrial cities anyway). If you need an author then maybe S. Lewis or Steinbeck (later).

Comment: @HotLicks There's absolutely nothing wrong with "Dickensian", it's just that I'd switch it to "Emily-Dickensian".  Surely only the most boorish of pedants in the US would notice the corruption of her name.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - "I didn't know that American schoolchildren read Charles Dickens, I've always heard it was Mark Twain, Fitzgerald, and Walt Whitman."  Yes, Dickens has often been assigned.  I checked if that's currently happening.  Maybe less, because it's long and dense, but still...: http://cornwallschools.enschool.org/Files%20and%20Documents/CCSD%20Curriculum%20Maps/English_English%20Language%20Arts%20(ELA)//Curriculum%20Map%20for%20English%209-12.pdf

Comment: "If I wanted to write about Black poverty in Chicago for instance, it would sound inappropriate, and non-American" [to refer to Dickens -- well, it all depends on the point you're trying to make.  I suppose I might think Gorky first, before Dickens.  But if Dickens bothers you then maybe Gorky would too? // I read a Theodore Dreiser book a long time ago and don't have a clear memory of it, but maybe that would be a comparable author in some ways?

Comment: @aparente001 I'm not bothered by Dickensian per se, in the question (ignore comments because I was getting frustrated with a particular user. Think: clarification) I was asking if there was an equivalent US author who spoke about poverty and hardship the same way as Dickens famously did. I happily admit ignorance and say I did not know who Gorky was, so I googled him, he's a Russian author.  I'll stick with *Dickensian*... and "post 9/11" which is what I used in the excerpt  I wrote  for a student. I was just showing her to be more creative with adjectives etc.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I'm sorry you had trouble with a particular user.  I assume you or someone else flagged some comments which were removed, because I read over this chain and didn't see the problem.  (Or maybe I'm just dense.)  I saw a play by Gorky once, called The Lower Depths.  Intense. // What was the context for your "post 9/11" and what were you conveying with that term?  Maybe there's something else on this page that would answer that -- sorry if I've missed it. // "Great Depression is difficult to use as an adjective" -- agreed; what I've seen is "Depression era" as an adjective.

Comment: I checked out of curiosity and apparently *Dreiserian* is a word -- but I'm not sure how much overlap it has with *Dickensian* -- whose definition I'm not 100% precise on to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that there is an  American author equivalent to  Dickens (Dickensian) whose name would suggest images of poverty, social inequalities etc. when we refer to "The Great Depression" period and its tragic consequences.

As the following [extract](https://www.bloomberg.com/view/articles/2013-08-11/how-the-great-depression-spawned-literary-masterworks) shows, of the authors that wrote about that period of the American History, none became so famous and popular to become an eponym in the  Dickensian sense:

> - When the stock market crashed in October 1929 and the hectic prosperity of the 1920s gave way to mass unemployment, the crisis energized American writers. After a decade in which the literary experiments of the Modernists -- Ernest Hemingway, F. Scott Fitzgerald, T.S. Eliot -- dominated the scene, ***a new wave of writers began to look to politics and economics for inspiration***.
> - What did the storytellers of the Depression know that our own writers don’t? And what can we learn from the writers of the 1930s about poverty and politics, literature and society? In this series, I will look at four Depression classics -- ***John Dos Passos***’s “The Big Money,” ***Edmund Wilson***’s “The American Jitters,” ***James Agees*** “Let Us Now Praise Famous Men” and ***John Steinbeck***’s “The Grapes of Wrath” -- reading them to see whether and how these books still speak to us today.

(www.bloomberg.com)

The Great Depression itself is commonly cited to refer to conditions of extreme poverty, unemployment, social distress etc.:

> - In 2008, the U.S. suffered the most severe economic crisis since 1929. This was followed by a deep recession characterized by high unemployment, financial instability and government deadlock -- ***an echo of the problems that plagued the country during the Depression***, though in much less virulent form.

Also, note that the adjective Dickensian, is commonly used also in [AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Dickensian%3Aeng_us_2012%2CDickensian%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1880&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDickensian%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CDickensian%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Of those four authors, Steinbeck is by far the most famous. And three of his best known novels — *Of Mice and Men*, *Cannery Row*, and *The Grapes of Wrath* — are set during the Depression.

Comment: But... https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Steinbeckian does exist. But I think that refers to his style of writing. His books are very well-known.

Comment: @PeterShor - I am aware that Steinbeck is the most famous among them, but his name is not commonly associated,  as far as I know, to conditions of extreme poverty, unemployment, and social distress.

Comment: Yes, but of those four authors, I think John Steinbeck is the only one a lot of  people will have heard of and would associate with the Depression. And if you think of a novel about the Depression, *The Grapes of Wrath* is one of the first that comes to mind.

Comment: @PeterShor - Yes but that is not the point here. As an AmE native, have you ever heard about  the expression: a "Steinbeckian poverty" for instance? in the way Dickensian would be used?

Comment: I think there's two questions in the OP. (1) *"which American author would evoke the same imagery and connotations as Dickens" [in evoking the Great Depression]*? I think the answer to this in unquestionably Steinbeck. (2) Should I use his name as an adjective with regard to this? And as you say, the answer to the second is "no".

Comment: @PeterShor - no, the question is on the adjectival usage of an author name with  strong correlations to poverty issues. Steinbeck wouldn't  work here.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is to just use **dickensian**. While the effort to find a local reference is appreciated (really, I wish more people would undertake such an effort), Dickens is an author who is commonly read in the united States. In middle-high school, we tend to read Great Expectations or A Tale of Two Cities (and maybe Oliver Twist), but A Christmas Carol is a perennial favorite.

And, even if we haven't read his works, we often know him by reputation or just by having seen the word dickensian enough in context (c.f. quixotic mission, kafkaesque experience, orwellian reality, faustian deal) to get the gist.

A few examples from major newspapers (it's hard to search for *dickensian* without pulling up tons of articles/books about Dickens himself, so I limited my searches to include newspaper names):

- *[Turkey’s Dickensian Disaster](https://nyti.ms/1m3q7AG)* (*New York Times*)
- *[No Happy Ending in Dickensian Baltimore](https://mobile.nytimes.com/2008/01/06/arts/television/06stan.html)* (NYT)
- *[Dickensian poverty in 2013](http://m.washingtontimes.com/news/2013/dec/24/lambro-dickensian-poverty-in-2013/)*  (*Washington Times*)

  > Most Americans, as we go about our daily lives, do not see these food lines because they’re working. People who need food are lining up every day in cities and towns across the country, a grim, *Dickensian testament* to the growing poverty that is all around us.
- *[A Nightmare Court, Worthy of Dickens](https://mobile.nytimes.com/2016/05/12/opinion/a-nightmare-court-worthy-of-dickens.html)* (NYT)

  > Over the next few years, Mr. Carridice, now 38, appeared 20 times in Bronx Criminal Court. [...]. In June 2015, more than a thousand days after his arrest, Mr. Carridice’s case finally went to trial. He was acquitted on all counts.
  >   This *Dickensian nightmare* is all too common in the Bronx, according to a class-action lawsuit filed Tuesday in Federal District Court by the Bronx Defenders, which represents indigent clients, and by two private law firms.

(although I don't really agree with its use in that last one).

- [Ditching *Dickensian*](https://www.theparisreview.org/blog/2014/04/30/ditching-dickensian/) [used 36 times in the article](*The Paris Review*)

  > *Dickensian* and its variations have been with us since at least 1856, when the OED identified the *Saturday Review* as referring to a “Dickensian description of an execution.” Variants of the term blossomed throughout the nineteenth century: *Dickenesque*, *Dickensy*, *Dickensish*, *Dickeny*. And their uses, unsurprisingly, run the gamut. Sometimes they indicate a certain comic sensibility; sometimes they refer to sordid working conditions, or to grotesque characterizations, or to acuity of social observation.

(I'll <del>clean up the links and</del> give commentary when I get to a computer, hard to C&P clips from mobile)

Comment: The *Washington Times* uses the term, that's true. But it explains the meaning by rehashing the plot of *A Christmas Carol*. I don't think the term is used in the USA much out of literary or journalistic circles, and even when it is, as in the *Times*, it is not used w/o explanation. I don't think it's a term that resonates that much with Americans. (It smacks of London to me.) I had the pleasure of never having to read one of his novels in school/college. We stuck to Shakespeare, Twain, Steinbeck, and other American authors. Most Americans know Dickens only through Walt Disney productions.

Comment: @Clare: Both my daughter and I had to read one his novels for high school, so it must depend on the school district.

Comment: @Clare My kids have been in *Oliver!* twice in the past nine years through the local children's theater, and *Great Expectations* was the only novel I had to read in 9th grade English in an entirely different state (in an inner city school), so I have to agree with Peter Shor that it must vary by school district.

Comment: @Clare  "I had the pleasure of never having to read one of his novels in school/college". I am bound to observe that it was the best of times, it was the worst of times for you. You poor thing!